# How did this good question even get into the close queue?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close, review

[This question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/31988/where-is-the-fuse-box-on-a-tgb-urban-125cc-scooter) seems perfectly worded and clear, and has not been edited at all which suggests it has had no issues from when it was first asked, and it has no downvotes.

Why has it been sent to the [review queue to close](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review/close/19194) as unclear what is being asked?

I cannot see anything wrong with this question and it is perfectly clear.

Am I being too nice? Or is this question "bad" in some way?

Comment: Your not being nice, your being logical.   :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because sometimes people are jerks?

*NOTE: I'm aware of the inherent irony in pointing out that sometimes people are a bit thoughtless through the use of name-calling.  That makes it double-irony!*

More productively, sometimes it's a little too easy to get annoyed at a stranger on the internet and click that close button a little too quickly.  We did just have the meta question that's germane to this point:

[Why are we so mean to new users?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/why-are-we-so-mean-to-new-users)

Just a reminder of the consensus: take a breath and think before reacting.  You have time to avoid being a little abrupt and coming across as really nasty to our users.  Civility, it's not a high bar.

Comment: One of the better answers I've read lately.  The last sentence tops it off quite nicely.

Comment: Casting a non-binding close vote makes somebody a jerk? And this is a site mod's viewpoint? Something is very wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Heh.... That was my fault :D

I voted to close the question for one simple, and in my opinion defensible reason.

From the "How to ask a good question" page:

> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Granted, it may not be grounds to close the question, but as the above quote specifically 'warns' against, the only answer on the question (at the time) was "Did you try looking in" this obvious place where it is on most bikes? That is a simple, obvious answer to what I saw as a simple, obvious question.

I do not think this falls under the category of "why are we so mean to new users" because at the time OP had 700 some-odd points; more than enough to understand how this site works, and in my opinion, enough to be held to a higher standard than a 'new' user.

As I admit in the comments yesterday, I was too quick to close after asking for more information. 'Unclear what you're asking' also didn't quite fit the bill, which should have been another hint that I *may* have been in the wrong, but all things considered, I stand by my decision, and thanks to OP's edits we have a better question because of it.

YOU SHOULD ALL BE THANKING ME!! :P

Comment: Actually, I don't agree that thanks are required for the system working as designed. Like you said, the commentary was all that was required to trigger some helpful edits. Mission accomplished. A close vote doesn't send a signal to the OP. It only alerts the other reviewers. There's also the problem that a close vote is a conversation stopper. It closes the discussion (thus the name) rather than clarifying it.

Comment: @BobCross The :P was supposed to indicate sarcasm, it's tough to convey through a keyboard. We all agree I was too quick on the draw with the close vote, I should have waited to see if OP would make a useful edit. I still think OP's question, before edit, was below the quality of this site. Had I not voted to close, I would have never known that 99% of review-eligible users disagree with me. I am now able to take another look at my intentions, and become a more constructive user. THAT is how I see the system working. I don't see how any of my actions have been "uncivil".

Comment: This is the "Seed Model" that Gerald M Weinberg writes about: "See yourself as a Learner instead of a loser." Great answer, I salute you!

Comment: @BobCross How is a close vote a conversation stopper? First the question is put *on hold*, not closed. Thus the name. Second, a vote itself does nothing, you need five -- if somebody is "too quick" then four other people also need to be "too quick", if a question is in the queue and shouldn't be there just click "Leave Open"... one vote is a total non-issue. Third, new users don't actually see that their question has any votes. Fourth, it doesn't stop comments at all, which is where all of our conversations happen. Fifth, there's a reopen button and a queue. Your statement is very confusing.